FileUpload to attachments()
I have a HeaderAction on a Filament resource. This Action contains a form and an actual action. The form accepts a FileUpload as follows:
FileUpload::make('attachments')
    ->label('Bijlagen')
    ->preserveFilenames()
    ->directory('/email/attachments')
    ->multiple()

The action on the form should grab the FileUpload and use it as an attachment in a Mailable.
Action:
->action(function (array $data) {
    Mail::to($data['recipient'])->queue(new GenericMail(subject: $data['subject'], body: $data['body'], attachments: $data['attachments']));
}),

Attachments function inside the Mailable:
public function attachments(): array {
    $attachments = [];

    if (!empty($this->attachments) && is_array($this->attachments)) {
        // Loop through each file path and create an Attachment instance
        foreach ($this->attachments as $filePath) {
            if (is_string($filePath) && !empty($filePath)) {
                $attachments[] = Attachment::fromStorage($filePath);
            }
        }
    }

    return $attachments;
}

When I work through my queue, this fails with the following error:

Cannot access offset of type string on string

I know I'm doing some bad array conversion but I can't seem to figure out what and where.
I have a HeaderAction on a Filament resource. This Action contains a form and an actual action.

don't show the line with the error on the log?

@francisco didn't understand your comment. can you elaborate?

check the logs for the line where the error happens
